# Sencha Touch 2: Trying to create a login form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I am a 100% newb to `Sencha` and am trying to take a stab at re-factoring my company's mobile app.

Here is my app.js:

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'RecruitTalkTouch',
    views: ['Login'],
    launch: function () {

        Ext.Viewport.add([
            { xtype: 'loginview' }
        ]);
    }
});
```

Login.js View:

```
Ext.define('RecruitTalkTouch.view.Login', {
  extend: 'Ext.Container',
  alias: "widget.loginview",
  xtype: 'loginForm',
  id: 'loginForm',
  requires: ['Ext.form.FieldSet', 'Ext.form.Password', 'Ext.Label', 'Ext.Button' ],
  config: {
    title: 'Login',
    items: [
      {
        xtype: 'label',
        html: 'Login failed. Please enter the correct credentials.',
        itemId: 'signInFailedLabel',
        hidden: true,
        hideAnimation: 'fadeOut',
        showAnimation: 'fadeIn',
        style: 'color:#990000;margin:5px 0px;'
      },
      {
        xtype: 'fieldset',
        title: 'Login Example',
        items: [
          {
            xtype: 'textfield',
            placeHolder: 'Email',
            itemId: 'userNameTextField',
            name: 'userNameTextField',
            required: true
          },
          {
            xtype: 'passwordfield',
            placeHolder: 'Password',
            itemId: 'passwordTextField',
            name: 'passwordTextField',
            required: true
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        xtype: 'button',
        itemId: 'logInButton',
        ui: 'action',
        padding: '10px',
        text: 'Log In'
      }
    ]
  }
});
```

Login.js Controller:

```
Ext.define('RecruitTalkTouch.controller.Login', {
  extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',
  config: {
    refs: {
      loginForm: 'loginForm'
    },
    control: {
      '#logInButton': {
        tap: 'onSignInCommand'
      }
    }
  },
  onSignInCommand: function(){
    console.log("HELLO WORLD");
  }
});
```

When I click the submit button, nothing happens. How can I hook up my submit button to listen for events (click, tap, etc) along with submitting the information to a backend API?

Answer (score 3):

In app.js file of your application, add:

```
controllers: [
        'Login'
    ]
```

in your application class. And for submitting information, call a Ajax request like this:

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
            url: // api url..,
            method: 'POST',
            params: {
                username: // get user name from form and put here,
                password: // get password and ...
            },
            success: function(response) {
                do something...
            },
            failure: function(err) {do ..}
        });
```

from inside onSignInCommand() function.

Answer (score 0):

You must activate your controller by adding it to the [`controllers`](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.2.1/#!/api/Ext.app.Application-cfg-controllers) option of your application class.

Then, to submit your data to the backend, you've got several options. You can use a [form panel](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.2.1/#) instead of your raw container, and use its [`submit`](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.2.1/#!/api/Ext.form.Panel-method-submit) method. Alternatively, you can use the [`Ext.Ajax`](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.2.1/#) singleton. In this case, you'll have to build the payload yourself. Finally, you can create a model with a configured proxy, and use its [`save`](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.2.1/#!/api/Ext.data.Model-method-save) method. This last way is probably the best for long term maintainability... Even if in the case of a simple login form, that may be a little bit overkill.

Comment: Can you give an example of the last thing you mentioned above?

Answer (score 0):

Can u please refer this sample app to create login form. Its very simple app please go through it.
http://miamicoder.com/2012/adding-a-login-screen-to-a-sencha-touch-application/